# Symfony2 creating twig extension

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

I want to create a simple twig extension `({{imgWidth(...)}})` that calls `getimagesize()` and returns the `width` and `height` of an image on the server.

I followed the instuctions you can find [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

When I reload my page I only can see a blank page - the `error.log` tells me that

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Fms\MediaBundle\Twig\Extension\ImgsizeExtension' not found in /var/www/fms/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4773

The **service** in `MediaBundle\Resources\config\services.yml` looks like:

```
services:
    twig.extension.imgsize:
        class: Fms\MediaBundle\Twig\Extension\ImgsizeExtension
        tags:
            - name: twig.extension
```

The **class** is:

```
<?
// src/Fms/MediaBundle/Twig/Extension/ImgsizeExtension.php
namespace Fms\MediaBundle\Twig\Extension;

class ImgsizeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('imgsize', array($this, 'imgWidth'))
        );
    }

    public function imgWidth($mediaId = 0, $mediaSize = 'L')
    {
        // ...
        return $mediaId;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'imgsize';
    }
}
```

Clearing cache via console or manually didnt help too.

Comment: A blank page suggest you are running in production mode while the error log indicates you are in development mode.  Double check that you are in development mode.  Do you get a profile bar without the extension?  It looks like your config is correct, I think you are running in production mode and that you have something else wrong.

Comment: Nah i'm in devMode. As soon as i remove the code in the service everything is ok (including the debug-bar).

Comment: Ok but in development mode I would expect errors to be shown right in the browser.

Comment: Yes i see errors in the most cases - maybe just an apache-misconfig or the like.
But Twig-Extension should work, but i get the same message even when i copy/paste the given example...

Comment: If it was me, I would resolve the errors.  Maybe update your question with a few of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<?` to `<?php`. I copied your code and in with this modification symfony finally finds this class.